Spring Batch Asynchronous Chunk Processing With Specific Item Grouping
I'm reading messages from the database, grouping them into chunks and passing those chunks to the thread pool for processing. So, each thread picks one chunk and processes it in the scope of one transaction.
The problem is that my processing logic lies in doing inserts/updates to 2 related database tables. There are sometimes cases when 2 threads try to do an operation on one (or several) column(s) in parallel and upon transaction(s) commit I receive either a deadlock or optimistic locking exception (entity that is being updated is versioned @Version).
Is there a way to group my items in a way that those that must be processed together (otherwise I have database inserts/updates issues described above) will go ONLY to one thread? Or maybe some fully different strategy has to be used?
All items that are meant to be grouped (processed by one thread have the same identifier);
I tried writing a synchronized block on a specific Mutex object (wrapped around that identifier) so that several thread can't process an item with the same identifier in parallel.
That helped me for some cases, but it's also a performance impact, so I'm searching for a better alternative.
